# How do I check for duplicates in one column in Excel only once duplicates have been identified in a previous column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a table of order data where instalment payments are used in Excel. The first column is the customer's email address and the second is the product they've bought. The third is whether the row is for an initial payment, or for a subsequent instalment payment.

I need to basically identify in the data whether or not any given customer has made instalment payments for a specific product. If they have made instalment payments, that customer will have multiple rows for a specific product. The data looks something like this.

```
CUSTOMER               COURSE            PAYMENT TYPE
joe@blogs.com          Course 1          First
bill@blogs.com         Course 1          First
joe@blogs.com          Course 2          First
joe@blogs.com          Course 1          Instalment
```

Basically, the formula would need to identify that whilst Joe has made three payments, only two of them are for the same course and therefore only one of them is an instalment payment. It would return something like 'Yes' in both the first and fourth rows as those rows are linked to the same customer with the same course.

How would I go about doing this? So far, I have only got as far as identifying where the customer has multiple rows, like so:

```
$A$2:$A$2579=A2
```

But this only identifies when the user has multiple orders, but doesn't take into account if those orders are for the same course, or what type of payment it is.

What would the formula look like to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.g. this formula:
`=IF( COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,B2)=1,"First","Installment")`

The key is using relative and absolute references together in order to refer only previous rows, not the whole range.

[image]